# Citable source for the sum of exterior angles of a simple polygon

Tags: proof-writing, angle, polygons

I'm trying to write my first paper, and as part of a proof of my conjecture I rely on the fact that the sum of the exterior angles of a simple polygon must equal $2\pi$.

Every high school student is taught this, and it says it [here on Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_and_external_angles).

However my professor suggested that I either reference the theorem by name or cite it from a reputable source.

I have searched the web but was unable to find a source like a published paper probing this fact, nor was I able to find a name for this. All I could find were math tutorials explaining it. I *could* try to prove it myself, but I don't want to make my paper like than it needs to be with trivial mathematics.

Where can I find a good, citable source for this fact?

Comment: I think that the polygon must also be convex to apply this result. There may be an extension to the non-convex case. Ok there is thanks @Abraham

Comment: @openproblem that's only when taking absolute values of exterior angles. If clockwise exterior angles are treated as negative then it equals 2π even for concave polygons. The definition of an exterior angle would be π minus the interior angle